# Creating objects in Java question

Tags: java

In PHP, to create a new object you would do something like this, `$dog = new Dog;`. But in Java you would do something like, `Dog x = new Dog;` or `Dog x;`. Could someone explain why you need to say the Dog class in front of the variable?

Comment: Because php, well... s**ks. (highly subjective)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Java statically and *explicitly* typed.

The type of the variable may be different from the type of the value it holds, due to inheritance. For example:

```
Animal dog = new Dog();
```

Here the type of the `dog` *variable* is `Animal`, but the value it holds is a reference to an instance of `Dog`.

Now in some other languages (C# 3 being the obvious example as a near neighbour of Java) you can use *implicitly typed local variables* when you actually want the type of a local variable  to be the same as the type of the expression used to initialize it:

```
var dog = new Dog(); // Equivalent to Dog dog = new Dog();
```

(The type inferencing capabilities of some other statically typed languages go well beyond this.)

So, to go back to your original question, the answer is:

- The `dog` variable has a type which is known at compile-time; this isn't true in PHP
- The type of the variable has to be explicitly stated in Java; this is related to static typing, but isn't a *requirement* of static typing

Answer (score 6):

You need to precise the type because Java is a **strong** and **static** typed language.

If you declare `x` as a **Dog**, it can only be a **Dog** or a subclass of **Dog**.

Another example :

```
public class Animal {
}

public class Dog extends Animal {
}

public class Cat extends Animal {
}
```

The following code is valid because `x` is declared as **Animal**, it can be a **Dog** or a **Cat**, or any subclass of **Animal** :

```
Animal x;
x = new Dog();
x = new Cat();
```

Comment: +1 for good, complete answer. I will just add that the type of the variable can be an interface too, as long as the class after the 'new' implements this interface.

Comment: It's possible to have a strong and static typed language that doesn't require you to declare the type twice (e.g. Scala). I think a more accurate answer is what you said plus "... and Java does very little in the way of type inference."

Answer (score 1):

In Java you would call the constructor like this (in case it has no parameters):

```
Dog x = new Dog();
```

By writing the class-name in front of the variable, you tell Java that your variable `x` is of type `Dog`. This allows Java to find out you're doing something wrong when writing:

```
Dog x = new Cat();
```

See [PHP Variables at w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/PHP/php_variables.asp):

> **PHP is a Loosely Typed Language**
>
> In PHP, a variable does not need to be
>   declared before adding a value to it.
>
> In the example above, you see that you
>   do not have to tell PHP which data
>   type the variable is.
>
> PHP automatically converts the
>   variable to the correct data type,
>   depending on its value.
>
> In a strongly typed programming
>   language, you have to declare (define)
>   the type and name of the variable
>   before using it.
>
> In PHP, the variable is declared
>   automatically when you use it.

Comment: It seems you like cats and dogs too ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because Java is strictly typed. You need to put the type of the object at compile time.

Answer (score 0):

Thats java syntax for creating an object of a class, also called as creating an instance.

For example, `Dog adog;`
where `adog` is a reference variable of type `Dog`.

`Dog adog=new Dog();` where `adog` is a reference variable of type `Dog` which is now referring to the `Dog` object in memory.

And you use the dot(.) operator to access the object's instance variables and methods.

Answer (score 0):

your class name object name = new class name();
 For Example

class Animal(){

//your code
}

Animal dog = new Animal();